# Какой тип данных выбрать для email в PostgreSQL

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, типы-данных

Есть ли специализированный тип данных для хранения email?
Или предется использовать символьные типы, такие как:

`character varying(n)`, `varchar(n)` - строка ограниченной переменной длины

`character(n)`, `char(n)` - строка фиксированной длины, дополненная пробелами

`text` - строка неограниченной переменной длины.

Принтскрин возможных вариантов типов данных в pgAdmin 4:
[image: возможные варианты типов данных]

Comment: [Аналогичный вопрос на DBA.SE](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/68266/106149).

Comment: @D-side Спасибо, я читал ее, но у меня нет возможности установить тип данных `CITEXT` или `varchar(254)` (вставил принтскрин возможных вариантов типов данных)

Comment: Эм, секунду, а чего это `varchar(254)` нет возможности использовать? Это ж встроенный тип.

Comment: @D-side вставил в вопрос картинку с возможными вариантами типов данных.

Comment: character varyng с Length = 254 то же, что и varchar(254).

Comment: Добавьте тогда ещё, каким инструментом пользуетесь. Потому что PostgreSQL это позволяет, а какой инструмент вас ограничивает, это уже другой вопрос. А `varchar` у вас это *character varying*. А ещё наверху какое-то поле ввода, наверняка позволяет ввести собственный тип.

Comment: @D-side, оформите комменты как ответ.

Comment: @BlackWitcher так у меня нет конкретной рекоменадции. И возможности проверить ответ на том же средстве, которым пользуется ТС, поскольку он его так и не назвал :)

Comment: character varying без размера, text, bytea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как уже говорили в комментариях (спасибо, [@D-side](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/181100/d-side)), аналогичный вопрос был на [DBA StackExchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/68266). Разумеется, там и ответ [есть](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/74313) :)

Кроме того, [pgAdmin 4](https://www.pgadmin.org/download/) — это одно (и [далеко не единственное](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Community_Guide_to_PostgreSQL_GUI_Tools#Open_Source_.2F_Free_Software)) из  открытых бесплатных средств администрирования Postgres (а есть еще и [пропиетарные](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Community_Guide_to_PostgreSQL_GUI_Tools#Proprietary)). Какие типы данных оно отображает в своём интерфейсе - это одно, а [типы данных, которые поддерживает сама СУБД](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/9.6/datatype.html) - это несколько иное.

С другой стороны, мы должны понимать, а что же именно мы хотим хранить и какое оно бывает? Для этого можно глянуть непосредственно стандарт, описанный как [RFC 821](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc821/?include_text=1). В стандарте нас интересует возможная длина адреса (описано на стр. 42), и она составит 129 символов. 
Но раньше существовал еще и другой стандарт **RFC 2821 Simple Mail Transfer Protocol** (устарел), где длина адреса была до 255 символов. Подробнее можно почитать [тут](http://www.remoteshaman.com/programming/common/rfc-the-best-guide-to-standards). Стандарт-то может и устарел, но гарантий, что уже и нет адресов длиной в 255 символов никто не даст. 
Потому давайте все же перестрахуемся, и будем считать, что 255 - это максимальная длина адреса электропочты.

Еще нас интересует, чувствителен ли адрес e-mail к регистру букв? Доверившись английской версии [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9808332/6935496) и стандарту [RFC 5321, раздел 2.3.11](http://rfc2.ru/5321.rfc/12#p2.3.11), получается, что часть адреса до собачки вроде как может быть чувствительна к регистру букв.

В то же время, на SO по ссылке выше говорится, что согласно RFC 1035, section 3.1, адрес домена не чувствителен к регистру. Проверять не будем, так как даже того, что часть адреса до собаки может быть регистрозависимой, нам достаточно, чтобы понять, что для хранения адреса нам нужен такой тип, который мог бы хранить регистрозависимые данные.

Итого - нам нужен чувствительный к регистру тип, в котором можно хранить 255 символов.

Автор вопроса пользуется pgAdmin 4 и предоставил скрин с возможным выбором типов данных. Итак, выбор не богат, но вполне достаточен. 
Смотрим в документацию по PostrgeSQL, и видим, что тип **Character varyng** - [это синоним](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-character.html) для **varchar**. Собственно, на английском SO [это мнение разделяют](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1199483/6935496) :)

Итого, тип **character varing**, изображенный на скриншоте, чувствителен к регистру букв и может иметь заданную размерность, которая задается в поле Lenght в интерфейсе pgAdmin 4, что привел автор вопроса.

Более того, этот тип является частью стандарта SQL, и, вдруг, если [deleted]завтра война[/deleted], потребуется переезд на другую платформу (читай - на другой движок БД), то проблем с переносом этого поля не будет (как и многих других сложностей, если бы тип был бы уникальным только лишь для Postgres).

Стало быть, его и надо использовать :)

А вообще, можно еще навесить на поле констрейнты или триггеры, которые бы при вводе/изменении данных в поле для хранения e-mail проверяли бы его валидность. Но это уже тема для отдельного вопроса. Хотя, если хотите, то можно и проверять регуляркой, [например](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10164872/6935496). Хотя лично сам я больше склоняюсь в пользу [такого решения](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4912087/6935496) по проверке валидности адреса (использовать почтовый ящик с указанным адресом как часть регистрационного процесса), хотя, разумеется, такой вариант может быть не всегда удобен.

Как итог - используйте **character varyng**, он же **varchar** и не парьтесь. :-)

Comment: Названия типов правило указаны в pgAdmin. Какой тип нечувствителен к регистру символов?